# android game in java

Tags: java, android, eclipse

i'm new on android and i'm trying to make a game in it but when i run the code in emulator than it shows the message "Force close" . I'm writing the splash screen and menu code in same class . It run fine when i didn't add the onclicklistner in the code but when i want to add the button action in the main code it close.

Here is my main class code

```
package com.gillidanda;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ViewSwitcher;

public class GilliActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

//creates a ViewSwitcher object, to switch between Views
    private ViewSwitcher viewSwitcher;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //Initialize a LoadViewTask object and call the execute() method
        new LoadViewTask().execute();
       // setContentView(R.layout.activity_gilli);

        Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b1.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(v.getId()==R.id.button1){
            //Log.d("Amit","Button clicked");

                       startActivity(new Intent(GilliActivity.this,StartGame.class));
        }
    }

    //To use the AsyncTask, it must be subclassed
    private class LoadViewTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void>
    {
        //A TextView object and a ProgressBar object
        private TextView tv_progress;
        private ProgressBar pb_progressBar;

        //Before running code in the separate thread
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() 
        {
            //Initialize the ViewSwitcher object
            viewSwitcher = new ViewSwitcher(GilliActivity.this);
            /* Initialize the loading screen with data from the 

                      'loadingscreen.xml' layout xml file. 
             * Add the initialized View to the viewSwitcher.*/


                     viewSwitcher.addView(ViewSwitcher.inflate(GilliActivity.this,         

                     R.layout.activity_gilli, null));

            //Initialize the TextView and ProgressBar instances -     

                              IMPORTANT: call findViewById() from viewSwitcher.
            tv_progress = (TextView) 

                            viewSwitcher.findViewById(R.id.tv_progress);
            pb_progressBar = (ProgressBar) 

                            viewSwitcher.findViewById(R.id.pb_progressbar);
            //Sets the maximum value of the progress bar to 100             
            pb_progressBar.setMax(100);

            //Set ViewSwitcher instance as the current View.
            setContentView(viewSwitcher);
        }

        //The code to be executed in a background thread.
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) 
        {
            /* This is just a code that delays the thread execution 4 

                              times, 
             * during 850 milliseconds and updates the current 

                                 progress. This 
             * is where the code that is going to be executed on a 

                                background
             * thread must be placed. 
             */
            try 
            {
                //Get the current thread's token
                synchronized (this) 
                {
                    //Initialize an integer (that will act as a 

                                              counter) to zero
                    int counter = 0;
                    //While the counter is smaller than four
                    while(counter <= 4)
                    {
                        //Wait 850 milliseconds
                        this.wait(850);
                        //Increment the counter 
                        counter++;
                        //Set the current progress. 
                        //This value is going to be passed 

                                                    to the onProgressUpdate() method.
                        publishProgress(counter*25);
                    }
                }
            } 
            catch (InterruptedException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        //Update the TextView and the progress at progress bar
        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) 
        {
            //Update the progress at the UI if progress value is 

                             smaller than 100
            if(values[0] <= 100)
            {
                tv_progress.setText("Progress: " + 

                                    Integer.toString(values[0]) + "%");
                pb_progressBar.setProgress(values[0]);
            }
        }

        //After executing the code in the thread
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) 
        {
            /* Initialize the application's main interface from the 

                                     'main.xml' layout xml file. 
             * Add the initialized View to the viewSwitcher.*/


                         viewSwitcher.addView(ViewSwitcher.inflate(GilliActivity.this, 

                              R.layout.mainmenu, null));
            //Switch the Views
            viewSwitcher.showNext();
        }
    }

    //Override the default back key behavior
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() 
    {
        //Emulate the progressDialog.setCancelable(false) behavior
        //If the first view is being shown
        if(viewSwitcher.getDisplayedChild() == 0)
        {
            //Do nothing
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            //Finishes the current Activity
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_gilli, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

Here is the splash screen code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/images" >

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/pb_progressbar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="18dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_progress"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/pb_progressbar"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:shadowColor="#000000"
    android:shadowDx="2.0"
    android:shadowDy="2.0"
    android:shadowRadius="3.0"
    android:text="Progress: 0%"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_loadingtext"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/pb_progressbar"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="19dp"
    android:text="Loading, please wait..."
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the mainmenu code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/tile" >


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="81dp"
        android:text="Start Game" />




    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="Help" />




    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:text="Setting" />




    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:text="Credits" />





    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="Exit" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the manifest code

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.gillidanda"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".GilliActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_gilli" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".StartGame"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_gilli" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.StartGame" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

pls give me some useful answer. Thanks for your reply.

This is my log code

```
08-13 16:05:02.257: D/AndroidRuntime(450): Shutting down VM
08-13 16:05:02.257: W/dalvikvm(450): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception   

(group=0x40015560)
08-13 16:05:02.276: E/AndroidRuntime(450): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-13 16:05:02.276: E/AndroidRuntime(450): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start  

activity ComponentInfo{com.gillidanda/com.gillidanda.GilliActivity}:  

java.lang.NullPointerException
08-13 16:05:02.276: E/AndroidRuntime(450):  at  

android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
08-13 16:05:02.276: E/AndroidRuntime(450):  at  

android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
08-13 16:05:02.276: E/AndroidRuntime(450):  at 

android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
08-13 16:05:02.276: E/AndroidRuntime(450):  at 

android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
08-13 16:05:02.276: E/AndroidRuntime(450):  at  

android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-13 16:05:02.276: E/AndroidRuntime(450):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-13 16:05:02.276: E/AndroidRuntime(450):  at 

android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
08-13 16:05:02.276: E/AndroidRuntime(450):  at 

java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-13 16:05:02.276: E/AndroidRuntime(450):  at   

java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-13 16:05:02.276: E/AndroidRuntime(450):  at 

com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
08-13 16:05:02.276: E/AndroidRuntime(450):  at 

com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
08-13 16:05:02.276: E/AndroidRuntime(450):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native 

Method)
08-13 16:05:02.276: E/AndroidRuntime(450): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-13 16:05:02.276: E/AndroidRuntime(450):  at com.
gillidanda.GilliActivity.onCreate(GilliActivity.java:27)
08-13 16:05:02.276: E/AndroidRuntime(450):   at 

android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
08-13 16:05:02.276: E/AndroidRuntime(450):  at 

android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
08-13 16:05:02.276: E/AndroidRuntime(450):  ... 11 more
08-13 16:05:49.157: D/AndroidRuntime(459): Shutting down VM
08-13 16:05:49.176: W/dalvikvm(459): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception 

(group=0x40015560)
08-13 16:05:49.216: E/AndroidRuntime(459): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-13 16:05:49.216: E/AndroidRuntime(459): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start  

activity ComponentInfo{com.gillidanda/com.gillidanda.GilliActivity}: 

java.lang.NullPointerException
08-13 16:05:49.216: E/AndroidRuntime(459):  at  

android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
08-13 16:05:49.216: E/AndroidRuntime(459):  at 

android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
08-13 16:05:49.216: E/AndroidRuntime(459):  at  

android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
08-13 16:05:49.216: E/AndroidRuntime(459):  at 

android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
08-13 16:05:49.216: E/AndroidRuntime(459):  at 

android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-13 16:05:49.216: E/AndroidRuntime(459):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-13 16:05:49.216: E/AndroidRuntime(459):  at 

android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
08-13 16:05:49.216: E/AndroidRuntime(459):  at  

java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-13 16:05:49.216: E/AndroidRuntime(459):  at 

java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-13 16:05:49.216: E/AndroidRuntime(459):  at 

com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
08-13 16:05:49.216: E/AndroidRuntime(459):  at 

com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
08-13 16:05:49.216: E/AndroidRuntime(459):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native  

Method)
08-13 16:05:49.216: E/AndroidRuntime(459): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-13 16:05:49.216: E/AndroidRuntime(459):  at 

com.gillidanda.GilliActivity.onCreate(GilliActivity.java:27)
08-13 16:05:49.216: E/AndroidRuntime(459):  at 

android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
08-13 16:05:49.216: E/AndroidRuntime(459):  at andr
oid.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
08-13 16:05:49.216: E/AndroidRuntime(459):  ... 11 more
08-13 16:05:53.677: I/Process(459): Sending signal. PID: 459 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Do you get an error output to the log? If so, include the details.

Comment: Add comments to indicate when the code actually fails.

Comment: which exception you are getting actully? please add your log statement here.

Answer (score 1):

you have not done a setcontentView in oncreate so findviewbyid fails.

```
setContentView(R.layout.mainmenu)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have run your code. I am getting null pointer exception at your

```
b1.setOnClickListener(this)
```

The only reason why findViewById returns null is because the button you are looking for do not belong to the current view.
If you add

```
setContentView(R.layout.mainmenu)
```

to your onCreate() it should work without exceptions.